# Append text around every line in a block in vim

Tags: vim

Original text

```
a = 2
b = 33
c = 456
```

Desired text

```
print("a = 2")
print("b = 33")
print("c = 456")
```

The example is just to illustrate the desired outcome; it has nothing to do with my program's goal.

How can I append `print("` to the beginning of every line and `")` to the end of every line? When I use visual mode `Ctrl-V` I can do the first operation but not the second because the line lengths are different.

Comment: Mark the lines (with `Shift-V`), then `:'<,'>s/.*/print("&")/` (see `:h s/\&`)

Comment: @SatoKatsura this is a great way to do it :)!

Comment: Mark the lines (with `Shift-V`), then `:'<,'>g//exe "norm! Iprint(\"\<C-o>A\")"`

Comment: another option is the visual block with `ctrl-v`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a macro. Put your cursor anywhere on the first line and type

```
qaIprint("<esc>A")<esc>jq
```

This breaks down as follows

```
qa       # start recording macro a
I        # enter insert mode at the beginning of the line
print("  # enter text
<esc>    # leave insert mode
A        # enter insert mode at the end of the line
")       # enter text
<esc>    # leave insert mode
jq       # move to the next line and stop recording
```

You can then run this repeatedly by typing `@a`.
If you know how many lines you want to change, you can append a count.
For example: `50@a` will run it 50 times and modify the next 50 lines.

Comment: @Iwassink Perfect! :)